# How to Create a cron job to backup ghost blog directory

Tags: 14.04, bash, backup, cron, dropbox

I installed dropbox_uploader and set it up. I've successfully created a backup from the command line, now I'd like to make it a script and make it run at midnight daily. Can someone help me create a cronjob for this? I know very little, but hey I got this far with google...

Here's what I pasted together based on commands I actually used to successfully backup my directory to dropbox and some googling of what i'm thinking. This doesn't work, but hopefully it shows what needs to happen and someone can make this work? Thanks for any help!

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_DIR="/tmp/"
DATE=$(date +"%m.%d-%Y")
BKP_FILE="$TMP_DIR/ghost_backup_$DATE.tar"
BKP_DIRS="/var/www/ghost_backup"
DROPBOX_UPLOADER=/root/dropbox/dropbox_uploader.sh

service ghost stop

cd /var/www

sudo cp -r ./ghost /tmp/ghost_backup

service ghost start

tar cf "$BKP_FILE" $BKP_DIRS
gzip "$BKP_FILE"

rm -rf ghost_backup/

$DROPBOX_UPLOADER -f /root/.dropbox_uploader upload "$BKP_FILE.gz" .

rm -fr "$BKP_FILE.gz"
echo "Successfully backed up Ghost folder to DropBox"
```

Then for the cron job I was thinking the following command:

`00 00 * * *     /var/www/backup.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/backup.log`

Comment: First, you had some quotation issues that I edited. Some quotations aren't closed, and it looks like you aren't using a code editor (you have ascii quotes instead of standard code quotes (")). If/when the edit is reviewed and uploaded, test your code out then. Otherwise look over your code and use something like `gedit` to edit it, not a word processor. Close quotes and it might work for you.

Comment: Also, are you putting this in `/etc/crontab`? If so, you need to add a user before the command to execute. Either `root` or your username.

Comment: Approved the comments, thanks. I'm looking for confirmation that the service stop and start will work and other general structure. I've never created a script before. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zzzach... Please move your comment to an answer :) Thank you

Comment: @EricPiekarczyk   I moved the comments to an answer. Accept it if it helped you solve the problem so others know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looked like you previously had some quotation issues. Using ascii quotes won't work well with code, use the standard coding quote (") instead.

Ascii quotes come from word processors like libreoffice or abiword; don't use those programs for coding. Use something like gedit or leafpad.

Also, are you putting this in /etc/crontab? If so, you need to add a user before the command to execute. Either root or your username. This is an example of a correct /etc/crontab job line:

```
10 6    * * *   root    bash /home/myusername/myscript.sh
```